# Strange output while comparing engineering numbers in AWK

Tags: bash, awk

In my script, I need to compare engineering numbers and keep the ones that are above my threshold. My input file:

```
8.63384676823803E-1439,1.59426879513427E-1589,6.30982615035767E-2151,2.28965973937211E-8,7.2400080082093E-470
```

My code is:

```
b=5; awk -v var=$b -F "," '{a=$var; if (a >= 1E-10) {a=$var} else {a=0}; print a}' inputfile
```

However, for `b = 5 (or 1/3/4)` I get `a = 7.2400080082093E-470`, whereas plain comparison `awk 'END {if ( 7.2400080082093E-470 >= 1E-10) print "wrong"}' inputfile` seems to work fine.

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your numbers are just too large (or small) for the AWK to understand them.

With GNU AWK you can use an arbitrary [precision integer extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arbitrary-Precision-Integers.html), as activated with `-M` command line switch to overcome that.

As of specific mechanism of why your comparison with a variable fails.

When it gets a number too large/small to understand, it treats it like a string instead.

```
%b=5; awk -v var=$b -F "," '{ a=$var; print a; }' inputfile 
7.2400080082093E-470
```

Then a lexicographical comparison of "7.2400080082093E-470" > 1E-10 yields "true"

(now let's forcibly convert it to number)

```
%b=5; awk -v var=$b -F "," '{ a=$var+0; print a; }' inputfile 
0
```

Numeric comparison "0 > 1E-10" yields "false", and it is the same thing that happens if you specify a big integer literal by hand (i.e. `print 7.2400080082093E-470` --> `0`).

With the arbitrary-precision arithmetics enabled:

```
b=5; awk -M -v var=$b -F "," '{ a=$var+0; print a; }' inputfile 
7.24001e-470
```

Comment: Zeppelin, thank you for your answer! That works for me. However, I still didn't get why the problem occurs only when the number is wrapped into a variable, because if you compare these plain numbers it work fine (`awk 'END {if ( 7.2400080082093E-470 >= 1E-10) {print "wrong"} else {print right}}' inputfile` will give you "right")

Comment: @MirrG When you use a plain numeric literal, it is just converted to `0`, before the comparison, which is why it looks like it works, try: `awk 'BEGIN { print 7.2400080082093E-470 }'`, with and w/o the `-M` switch.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with big numbers. Building latest AWK from sources worked for me.